# Using BerkeleyDB with Hadoop and Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, berkeley-db

I want to use BerkeleyDB with Hadoop and Spark is there any guide/tutorials available to run berkeley db over the cluster of multiple nodes (I have 8 nodes cluster)

1. Is it a right choice to use Berkeley to store BigData for analytics? As i        want Tree like structured DB
2. Is there any better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.
When we connect with berkeley db using

```
fileName = '/your/berkeley/file/path'
berkleyObject = bsddb3.btopen(fileName)
```

It basically gives us a dictionary to traverse containing complete data by which we can create dataframe using **pandas**

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(berkleyObject.items(),columns=['Key','value'])
```

and then we can load this data frame into Spark's SqlContext

```
sparkDF = sparkSql.createDataFrame(df)
```

I havent tried creating dataframe directly from berkeley bsddb3 object but i am sure it will work too

```
sparkSql.createDataFrame(berkleyObject.items())
```

As spark's dataframe is distributed like RDD so all the Sql queries we make will utilize spark's distributed processing i.e. It will run queries parallel on all slave/worker nodes.

```
sparkDF.registerTempTable("Data")
result = sparkSql.sql("SELECT * FROM Data WHERE Key == 'xxxx' ")
```

Only catch is the process converting Dictionary object into DataFrame object is too slow. I am still working on it.

Comment: Did you figure it out how to load the Berkeley DB efficiently in Spark?